# How to use Axios to fetch data from Google Places API in React Native and display it in UI?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, axios

Trying to get a restaurant name from Google Places API.

First page displays the list of restaurants, and when user selects one, it passes place_id as an 'id'value to a second page (that I'm currently working on).

I managed to grab the data and it displays in console [line 23 console.log(result); displays data in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw5cj.jpg)

However, in line 36 {result.name} displays nothing. As I set useState(null), I wonder if it empties it before it gets to the ?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Flatlist, Image } from 'react-native';
import axios from "axios";
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const GResultsShowScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    
    const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
    const baseURL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=MYAPIKEY';
    const id = navigation.getParam('id');
    const getResult = async (id) => {

    const response=  await axios.get(`${baseURL}`, {
            params: {
                        place_id: id
                    }}
        );

        setResult(response.data);
        
    };

    console.log(result);

    useEffect(() => {
        getResult(id);
    }, []);
    
   
    if (!result) {
         return console.log('nodata');
        }
    
    return (
    <View>       
         <Text>test {result.name} </Text>  
    </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default GResultsShowScreen;type here
```

and this is the console output by console.log(result); so at this point there is data in result

[console output]
[console output in plain textview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKcUc.jpg)

Comment: Please share console output as the plain text format

Comment: Thanks, I've loaded a screenshot of the output of text format.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you can add conditional rendering to handle the case when the result is null or empty. Instead of using console.log in the if (!result) condition, you can return a loading indicator or a placeholder text while waiting for the data to be fetched.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

const GResultsShowScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
  const baseURL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=MYAPIKEY';
  const id = navigation.getParam('id');

  const getResult = async (id) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`${baseURL}`, {
        params: {
          place_id: id
        }
      });
      setResult(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error fetching restaurant details:', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getResult(id);
  }, []);

  if (!result) {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Loading...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Restaurant Name: {result.name}</Text>
      {/* Render additional restaurant details here */}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default GResultsShowScreen;
```

The component will display "Loading..." when the result is null, indicating that the data is still being fetched. Once the data is fetched and stored in the result state, the component will render the restaurant name. Change the MYAPIKEY with yours in baseurl